# RedBoot Cannot Run from DDR

Tags: assembly, embedded, arm

I'm working on a new board based on iMX31 platform, this board has a 
single chip 256MB LPDDR from Micron (MT46H64M32LFCM-6) and I use NAND to 
boot the board (BOOT[4:0] = 00001).

We know that once RedBoot starts to run, it'll first initialize the system, then copy 
the first 2KB of its code from NAND to DDR, then jump to the memory location of 
DDR and run code from there. But in my case, a changing to program counter just 
turns my board into a silent brick. The following is the code snippet I'm talking 
about:

```
1:  ldmia r0!, {r3-r10}
    stmia r1!, {r3-r10}
    cmp r0, r2
    blo 1b

    /* Jump to SDRAM */
    ldr r1, CONST_0x0FFF
    and r0, pc, r1     /* offset of pc */
    ldr r1, MXC_REDBOOT_ROM_START
    add r1, r1, #0x10
    add pc, r0, r1
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    ...
```

Once the `add pc, r0, r1` gets executed, the whole thing stops. I'd verified my DDR 
initialization is correct (all the timing parameters, ROW=14, COL=10 and data bus 
size=x32), and I had ran several memory tests with no failure, so I'm pretty 
confident the controller and memory chip itself are fine. In RedBoot, everything 
looks and works well until I have to manually set the value of program counter to 
somewhere in the range of DDR memory map.

I've stuck here for a few days now, I double-checked the data I copied into DDR 
was identical to those in NAND, and the value of PC was also correct.

Please help, thanks!

Comment: How are you handling your caches? Are you using it? Do you flush it before trying to execute your new code? If it's on, try turning cache off and see if that helps..

Comment: @Splat L2 cache is disabled during initialization of the CPU.

Comment: Is the memory range containing the RAM enabled for execution? If not it'll throw an exception, and you may not have those set up yet.

Answer (score 1):

The ARM did not just stop, so it will be useful to determine where execution actually continues.  It will be one of two places:

1. The PC value that you wrote to the pc.  This may or may not be where you expect it to be. if possible use a  debugger to verify that R0 & R1 actually is the location in SDRAM that you expect.
2. An exception, probably an abort exception like prefetch abort.  This means that the instruction that is stored at PC was in a memory location that was not accessible due to permissions on the MMU or due to a configuration problem (SDRAM?).

I would set 'traps' on the interrupt vectors that make them loop to themselves.  That way you can see wherever PC points to after a 'hang' will tell you what happened.

In assembly it looks like this:

```
B   _reset  /* Reset */
B   .   /* Undefined Instruction */
B   .   /* Software Interrupt*/
B   .   /* Prefetch Abort*/
B   .   /* Data Abort*/
B   .   /* Reserved*/
B   .   /* IRQ*/
B   .   /* FIQ*/
```

Just locate this code at the beginning of memory (0x00000000) and rerun the program.  If it hangs at 0x0000000C (prefetch abort) or 0x000000010 (data abort) then it is the probably the SDRAM config or MMU permissions. If it hangs somewhere else then it is a problem with the code loading the PC, probably loading it with the wrong address.

Hope that helps!